# Error con palabras en Java - "error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int"

Tags: java

Aquí está el código que da error:

```
int frase;
frase = "hola";
```

Y el error señalando a la última de estas líneas:

> error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

Comment: Y que error obtienes, o que quieres lograr?, a simple vista es solo un error de tipos

Comment: Cualquiera de las respuestas de abajo te solucionarán el problema.
Echale un vistazo a la respuesta de @Error404 ya que además te explica un poco mas cosas del lenguaje.

Comment: @danlos no olvides marcar como correcto la respuesta que mas te ayude

Comment: Podrías marcar como resuelta esta pregunta? :)

Answer (score 8):

Java es un lenguaje en el cual tienes que declarar el tipo que se va a almacenar en cada una de las variables. En este caso estás intentando introducir un String en un número entero y por eso te da el error.

```
String frase;
frase = "hola";
```

Por otro lado, si lo que quisieras almacenar fuera un número entero, deberías utilizar el valor `int`.

```
int numero;
numero = 5;
```

Tienes que tener en cuenta que cuando declaras una variable con su tipo **no va a modificar su tipo en toda la ejecución del programa**.

Answer (score 2):

Danlos, bienvenido a la comunidad, tu error es el siguiente

La variable frase la declaras de tipo de dato `int` y este tipo de dato es solo para numeros enteros. Para declaras frases (palabras o textos) debes ocupar `String`

```
String frases;
frases = "hola";
```

Answer (score 1):

error de tipo

```
String frase;
frase = "hola";
```

las cadenas son string 
enteros son int

Answer (score 1):

Te da un error puesto que estás inicializando una variable de tipo `int` (número entero) cuando lo que tu necesitas es una variable de tipo `String` (tipo texto)

Opción en 2 lineas (Inicialización y Asignación):

```
String frase;
frase = "hola";
```

Opción en una linea (Inicialización + Asignación):

```
String frase = "hola";
```

Espero haberte ayudado :)

Comment: short es el número de entero corto saludos.

Answer (score 0):

`int` solo se utiliza para enteros(números).
Deberías declararlo como `String`(cadena).

```
String frase;
frase = "hola";
```

Answer (score 0):

Editado:

Ya se ha explicado en [esta respuesta del usuario @Error_404](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34139/17062), pero por darle un poco más de profundidad:

`int` es un tipo de dato que engloba valores numéricos enteros (no puedes guardar en un int un valor numérico con decimales). Las variables que guardas con `""`, no son ese tipo de valores, si no que son cadenas de texto, que se tipifican previamente con `String`.

Al asignar a un `int` (que sólo recibe números) un valor `String`, se produce ese error. Recuerda que en Java, las variables van tipadas —debes indicar el tipo para declararlas.

Comment: bienvenido a StackOverflow, Acá no existe realmente el concepto de _arriba_ y _abajo_ en cuanto a respuestas, ya que puedes ordenarlas por actividad, votos o antigüedad. Cuando haces referencia a otra(s) respuestas, es mejor que incluyas un vínculo a las mismas, para que quede claro a cual te refieres.

Comment: @jachguate , gracias, soy novato en este sitio.